# Weird memory leak with Blocks and copying in certain way in ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

The following simple code, under ARC, in the latest Xcode (4.6.2) shows leaks when profiled with the Leaks instrument, in iOS simulator, in Release build configuration with `-Os` optimization:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        void (^block)() = ^
        {
            NSLog(@"%d", i);
        };

        id x = block;
        [x copy];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

It shows 10 leaked blocks. (It does not show leaks with optimization turned off; but turning off optimization is not realistic for our app.) The strange thing is, looking at the memory management history for each of the leaked blocks, they look fine -- each has a malloc from the copy and a release; but the release somehow does not deallocate it?

Is this a compiler bug (it is using the default Apple LLVM compiler)?

Comment: Are you certain ARC is on? Try inserting a `-retain` and see if the compiler complains.

Comment: @KevinBallard: Yes, ARC is on. If ARC wasn't on, why would the leak go away when optimization is turned off? Plus, the block IS released, as seen in Instruments; it's just not deallocated.

Comment: What happens if you replace `id x = block; [x copy];` with `[block copy]` ?

Comment: @Ríomhaire: it goes away. it has to be a block type assigned to `id`, anything else won't reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be either a bug in the compiler or the leaks instrument, I am not sure which. You should file a bug with Apple.

The same leak also happens when shortening the code to this:

```
int i = 0;
void (^block)() = ^{
    int y = i;
};

id x = block;
```

The leak only appears if the block references a local variable from the parent scope.

Do you see this happening in real production code or only in this example?